# Firefox addon - Catch post variables before submit [no enctype]

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, tamper-data

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="includes/do.php">
    <input type="text" name="action" value="login" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="myemail@hotmail.com" />
    <input type="text" name="pass" value="helloworld" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Then, I want to catch the variables values before being submitted inside a `firefox addon observer`. Notice that the form DOESN'T have the attribute:  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. That's an important detail because I have a code that let me get the post data but it only works if `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

I'm sure I have to use:

```
var scrStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
                .createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream);
```

but I have not get a working code so far (I'm a beginner).

I wanna get something like:

```
{
    "action": "login",
    "email": "myemail@hotmail.com",
    "pass": "helloworld"
}
```

If you know about some function with the following interface, then better:

```
function get_post_data(channel) {
    var data;
    // ...
    return data
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have a `nsIUploadChannel` channel, you can read the contents of the stream and parse them as if they where `GET` parameters (e.g. `some=value&someother=thing`).

### Reading

```
var instream = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"].
               createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream);
instream.init(channel.uploadStream);
var data = instream.read(instream.available());
```

#### Keeping the original upload stream intact

There are some things to consider, though, if you want to have the original `.uploadStream` still working, namely you must not access `nsIMultiplexInputStream` instances at all (these will break) and you must check `nsISeekableStream` and rewind the stream.

```
var ustream = channel.uploadStream;
if (ustream instanceof Ci.nsIMultiplexInputStream) {
  throw new Error("multiplexed input streams are not supported!");
}
if (!(ustream instanceof Ci.nsISeekableStream)) {
  throw new Error("cannot rewind upload stream; not touching");
}
var pos = ustream.tell();
var instream = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"].
               createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream);
instream.init(ustream);
var data = instream.read(instream.available());
ustream.seek(0, pos); // restore position
```

If you replace the stream with `.setUploadStream` anyway, then these aren't much of a concern and can be ignored.

### Parsing

How exactly you parse the `GET` style parameters is up to you and discussed in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/484441) already.
Only thing to remember is, that usually `GET` parsers expect a leading `?` (e.g. `?some=value`), `POST` data does not have that (e.g. just `some=value`).